# SQLite Time Format Issues on Data Imported from a csv. A Number of Trailing Zeros

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, select

I was trying to query the duration of a WWE wrestler in the matches which he won and here I have successfully retrieved the data:
[image: A lot of trailing zeros after seconds]

I would like to remove those zeros and I tried the following piece of code:

```
strftime(%H:%M:%S, R1.time_in_match)
```

which doesn't work and give the following error:

```
 ': near "%": syntax error
```

The data I imported were from a data frame which stores the time as time object and put them into the database as type DATETIME. The typeof function used on the "time_in_match" field returned type TEXT.

I was wondering if there is any way to format the time.

Thanks!

Comment: `select strftime('%H:%M:%S', R1.time_in_match)` you missed the single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite provides 2 functions for this case:

```
strftime('%H:%M:%S', R1.time_in_match)
```

and simpler:

```
time(R1.time_in_match)
```

because:

> The `time()` function returns the time as *HH:MM:SS*

(from [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html))

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzdXTnhYMTkfcSpSJry9v3/0).

Answer (score 0):

Your expression works as intended if you surround the format specifier with single quotes:

```
strftime('%H:%M:%S', time_in_match)
```

You could also just use string functions here:

```
substr(time_in_match, 1, 8)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0c69509d1e92e4d0fd110875e9f398e2)**

Comment: Thanks, the first one doesn't work well. The second one is fine.

Comment: @Harry1024: the first one failed because I wrongly added single quotes around the identifier... fixed.